# Invoking method using reflection / Converting List to Var Args

Tags: java, list, reflection, invoke, variadic-functions

I have a list of parameters and I have the method name. I want to invoke the method using reflection. 
 When I checked the java doc for Method.invoke its like Method.invoke(object o, Object args...) .
 I know what to pass for the first paramter (i.e instance on which method to be invoked if its instance method) and args is the parameters for the method.

But now I have have the list which contains values which are to be passed to the method.

Say for example: I want to invoke method ClassName.methodName(String , int, int) and I have a List which contains {val1, 3, 4}.

Using reflection it may  be like Method.invoke (classNameInstance, ??????). But I am not sure how to convert a list of arguments to varargs and pass.

One way may be If i know that list size is 3 then I may write Method.invoke (classNameInstance, list.get(0), list.get(1), list.get(2)).

But some of the methods which I want to dynamically invoke take 0 to 12 arguments. So it doesn't look "good" to create switch case and write 12 cases. Each will check with number of parameters and build the separate call with parameters.

Any way to go about this except from using switch case?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Notation Object... means nothing more than Object[]. It is just syntactic sugar for an Arraynotation. Pass an Array and it will work.

Comment: Thanks so method.invoke(classNameInstance, argumentsList.toArray()); will work ....

Comment: Infact I tried with this this works fine if the List of one simple type. But say when API is (String, int, int ) and List<Serializable> : {"val1", "2","3"} . After converting them to array its giving issues as types is not matching. Means Before I can directly pass them into the the invoke method I need to type cast them to perticular type which matches with the method. If so I cannot directly convert to array and use. Correct me if i am mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**: this is a more general approach that works for any type of vararg params:

```
        Class<?> c = int.class;
        Object array = Array.newInstance(c, list.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
                Array.set(array, i, list.get(i));
        Test.class.getDeclaredMethod("test", array.getClass()).invoke(
                new Test(), new Object[] { array });
```

---

`void m(X...p)` has the same signature as `void m(X[] p)`. You cannot declare both in the same class.

Here is how to invoke them using reflection (primitives and non-primitives):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Test
{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                list.add(1); list.add(2); list.add(3);
                Test.class.getDeclaredMethod("test", Integer[].class).invoke(
                    new Test(), new Object[] { list.toArray(new Integer[0]) });
                int[] params = new int[list.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) params[i] = list.get(i);
                Test.class.getDeclaredMethod("test", int[].class).invoke(
                    new Test(), new Object[] { params });
        }

        public void test(int ... i) { System.out.println("int[]: " + i[0] + ", " + i[1] + ", " + i[2]); }
        public void test(Integer... i) { System.out.println("Integer[]" + Arrays.asList(i)); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this will for for int but this list of type List<Serializable> casting issues will come and type mismatch will be generated.

Comment: Added example w/ any type of vararg -- Class<?> c = int.class or whatever you want.

Answer (score -1):

Varargs is really just an array.

The method can be retrieved like this, assuming it takes `int...` args:

```
Method method = MyClass.class.getMethod("someMethod", int[].class);
method.invoke(myInstance, argumentsList.toArray());
```

Comment: List.toArray() will return Object[] -- not gonna work with "int..."